# interpretation of 玉を落とす in this sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs

> どうせ何【なん】かの玉【たま】を落【お】とすのは分【わ】かり切【き】ってる

This sentence uses 玉を落とす in a way that makes me think that 玉 is a noun being modified by を落とす to mean something like 'a ball intended to be dropped', in other words, a ball you'd play with in sports and the like.

Also, I'm not really sure about 何か being followed by の, is this a regular/fixed usage of 何か with any special properties?

If you need context for all this, let me explain a bit:

The person that says the sentence in question is skeptical about receiving the New Year's Gift お年玉【おとしだま】 from another person, and notices that other person is holding a ball, which turns out to contain money. Maybe it is a witty word game intended to show that the ball **玉** actually contained the New Year's Gift お年**玉**.

Comment: I am pretty amazed that people have already posted answers.  I am a Japanese-speaker but I could not even begin to answer this question without more context.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation is:

> It is obvious to me that you will be dropping some sort of balls anyway(after all).

The person saying this is playing a pun on the word "玉" as you said. The person is aware that he/she will either be receiving the "money (お年玉)" or the "ball（玉）".

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should describe the context more.

My guess is that it is in a comedy play or something.

Jerry: Hey, I will give you お年玉.

Tom: Oh really? Thanks. But you always trick me. I am sure you give me '落とし玉' but not 'お年玉.' I am not sure what it means, but it is obvious to me that you will be dropping some sort of balls and call it '落とし玉.' I won't be tricked anymore.

Jerry has a ball, which turns out to contain money.

何か: Something
何かの: Some sort of

Comment: Yes, is from something similar to Manzai comedy

Comment: OK, then I think my guess is correct.